# Expected value of visits to a node in a randomly constructed graph

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

A boy has n coins with **unique** weights. He chooses a coin **randomly** and places it at the first **empty** node. To reach the empty node he compares the coin he currently has with the coin at the node and proceeds left if the coin he has is lighter otherwise he proceeds right (he can just go left or right at every node). He keeps doing this until all coins are exhausted.

He gets to keep all the coins which are at the nodes he visited just once. What would be the expected value of his prize.

I can solve it using brute force for smaller values of n but that will not be efficient enough.

Other direction in which I can think is that if somehow we can manage the expectation of getting a coin with a weight w given the weights of other coins then we can sum up all such expectations. But I am unable to work this out.

*Note, even when a coin is placed at a node, visit count increases*

**Example**:

n=3 ; weights ε {1, 2, 3}

if he chooses 1,2,3 he will get 3 unit

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
```

if he chooses 1,3,2 he will get 2 unit

```
1
 \
  3
 /
2
```

if he chooses 2,1,3 he will get (1 + 3) = 4 unit

```
  2
 / \
1   3
```

if he chooses 2,3,1 he will get (1 + 3) = 4 unit

if he chooses 3,1,2 he will get 2 unit

if he chooses 3,2,1 he will get 1 unit

So, expected amount of weight is (3 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 1) / 6 = 8 / 3

Thanks.

Comment: If inserting a coin into the tree counts as a visit, then all of the leaf nodes would be included. If not, then you can count every node that only one child, and that child is a leaf node. It's hard to say what the value of the prize is without also telling us the order in which nodes are inserted, and what the individual coin denominations are. Or, for that matter, what constitutes "visiting" a node.

Comment: Even when a coin is placed at a node, visit count increases. We need to find the expected value of prize given n different weights. So the algorithm needs to somehow account for all possible permutations "indirectly". I've added an example, please have a look.

Comment: So basically you add up the values of all the root nodes. I think if you do a brute force study for n=4, you'll see a pattern in the possible scores, and you can probably exploit that to come up with your general solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example where it is much easier to solve it top down recursively and then memoize.

You have described a one coin at a time game.  But the expectation is exactly the same as if you took a random coin, then split all of them into smaller and larger piles, then did the same with each of those piles recursively.

Now figure out how to calculate that recursively.  Then memoize and you have your solution.